# IPV6 - private IP not working

Tags: ipv6, ipv4

I have an apache server with a simple php file `echo "hello world!";` and when I try:

- **http://[127.0.0.1]:8000** working fine
- **http://[192.168.1.2]:8000** working fine
- **http://[::]:8000** working fine
- **http://[fe80::b00:24ff:fe62:5fa4]:8000** not working

**192.168.1.2** is my private IPV4

**fe80::b00:24ff:fe62:5fa4** is my private IPV6

What is wrong here? Do I have to setup something?

Comment: What do the log files say? How is the system configured (config file excerpts). Give us details to actually help you.

Comment: `de80:` is not a valid prefix, if you want to use private addresses then use the proper ones (ULA)

Comment: @SanderSteffann Yes, sorry about it. I was trying to obfuscate the IP.

Comment: `fe80::b00:24ff:fe62:5fa4` is _not_ a private address, it is a link-local address. Any links you have on a device will use the same network for link-local addresses. This means that the host cannot tell from the address which link to use. Because of that, you must use the scope (e.g. %eth0 or %2) on the end of the address to distinguish which interface the host should use for that address. Unfortunately, the scopes don't work with browsers, so you can't use link-local addresses in browsers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are claiming is your private IPv6 address is *not* a private IPv6 address. With IPv6, private addresses are called ULA (Unique Local Address), and they are defined by [RFC 4193, Unique Local IPv6 Unicast Addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4193). The range for IPv6 ULA is `fc00::/7`, but the lower half of the addresses (`fc00::/8`) are reserved for a future global authority to assign. The second half of the ULA (`fd00::/8) is available for local use, but the following 40 bits (Global ID) *must* be randomly generated by an approved pseudo-random number generator in order to minimize the possibility of conflict.

What you are calling a private IPv6 address is actually a Link-Local IPv6 address (`fe80::/10`, see [RFC 4291, IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture, Section 2.5.6. Link-Local IPv6 Unicast Addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.5.6)). Every IPv6 interface on every link will use the same network for the link-local addressing. This causes a problem since a device could have multiple interfaces, and every interface will use the same link-local network. That means that a device cannot determine which interface you mean when using a link-local address. To overcome that, you use a scope (interface) on the end of the address, e.g. `fe80::b00:24ff:fe62:5fa4%eth0`. Unfortunately, the browser developers have not adopted this notation. That means you have no way to use an IPv6 Link-Local address with a browser.

You need to configure Global (`2000::/3`) or ULA addressing on your network in order to use IPv6 with your browser.